# How do I loop a portion of a track in Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-xp, windows-media-player

I'm using Windows XP SP3 and Media Player 11 and want to know how to loop a portion of a track in Windows Media Player.

Comment: While the [Windows Media Player Plus!](http://bmproductions.fixnum.org/index.htm?http://bmproductions.fixnum.org/wmpplus/index.htm) add-on doesn't seem to have this feature currently, if it's possible to implement I'm sure the developer would be willing to do so, so I recommend you drop him a mail.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with the stock player, but you can easily use a program like Audacity to cut the desired piece and repeatedly play it.

My more musically inclined friends use http://loopthetube.com/ for songs.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to accomplish this by creating a .asx file with the `STARTTIME`, `DURATION` and `REPEAT` elements, see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd564668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

And an example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx